# How do I properly create a PHP array in order to loop through later and grab each piece of info?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, email, phpmailer

I have a mysql table with a bunch of users (names, emails, and notify, which is either yes if they want email notifications or no if they don't).

I want to query all the names/emails/userid of the people that want notifications (i.e. notify='yes') and put them into an array for later use...

```
$sql = "SELECT userid, firstname, lastname, email, notify FROM users
    WHERE notify = 'yes'";
    $getnotify = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    if (!$getnotify) {
    die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error());
    } else {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getnotify)) {
            //get emails, add comma after if necessary
            $notifyemailsarray[$row['email']]=$row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']. " " . $row['userid'];
        }
    }
```

This works and outputs something like this:

```
Array
(
    [jj@gmail.com] => John Jones 331322
    [billw@yahoo.com] => Bill Wilson 331323
    [kenny896@gmail.com] => Kenny Smith 331347
    [gl222@hotmail.com] => Greg Lawson 331331
    [chrisc1987@gmail.com] => Chris Connors 331325
)
```

Two questions.

1. Minor side note question: If I have multiple entries in the database with the same email address (say "kenny896@gmail.com"), the array only has it once. It seems to be removing duplicates.  This actually is what I want in this case, but is this right?  Should it be doing that on its own?
2. Later on, using the array I created above, I use PHPMailer to send unique emails to each person on the list...

.

```
foreach($notifyemailsarray as $email => $name) {
    $mail->addAddress($email, $name);  // Add recipient
    $mail->Body = "Hi $name! Here's some stuff about you, User with the id number of $userid";
    $mail->AltBody = "";
        if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
        //mail sent     
        }
    // Clear all addresses for next loop
    $mail->clearAddresses();
}
```

Notice in the body, I have their name display (using $name).  That works fine.  But I also want to list out their userid # where I have "$userid".  How do I create the array initially (and construct the subsequent foreach loop) to make this easy?  Pretty sure sticking it after the name was the wrong approach in my code above (sorry, probably painful to look at haha).  In a nutshell, I want to create the array where it's then easy to grab each person's email, name and userid as I loop through and email each of them (so that their emails can be unique/personalized).

Comment: We didn't see any commentary from you - do these answers meet your needs?

Comment: Yes, sorry for delay, both answers were great, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, regarding the deduplication - yes, that is what PHP is doing. An associative array (by `email` in your case) can only have one of each key, so if your table has more than one row per email, only the **latest** one in the result set will be in your output array. Effectively, PHP overwrites the previous one if it encounters another. The best thing to do here is to fix your source data and remove duplicates there, if you don't want them to be present. Otherwise, there may be uncertainty as to *which* of the duplicates makes it into your output array if you can't be certain of their order in the source table.

Now to the array structure.  Consider indexing by `email` as you're already doing, but just keeping the entire row's fetched array with it rather than concatenating a string. You then have all the parts you need later when constructing your email, but you must assemble the first & last names at that time.  If you need to add any other details to the output email or if you add more columns to the table (and query) in the future, you'll already have them for use in the email.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getnotify)) {
    // Keep the entire fetched row, indexed by email
    $notifyemailsarray[$row['email']] = $row;
}
```

When building your emails, just access the values by their array key (column name).

```
// Loop over users, with $details array
foreach($notifyemailsarray as $email => $details) {
    // Assemble the fullname here
    $fullname = $details['firstname'] . ' ' . $details['lastname'];
    // Fullname is available in a variable now
    $mail->addAddress($email, $fullname);  // Add recipient
    // And the userid is in an array key
    $mail->Body = "Hi $fullname! Here's some stuff about you, User with the id number of {$details['userid']}";
    $mail->AltBody = "";
    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        //mail sent     
    }
    // Clear all addresses for next loop
    $mail->clearAddresses();
}
```

Note: This also keeps the `email` and `notify` keys in the array, which you can merely ignore. I would recommend you continue indexing by `email` though rather than just relying on the email value within the array because you still need it to handle your "accidental" deduplication by array key.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it is normal. The keys on an array must be unique. How will you differentiate them otherwise?
2. The easiest way will be to store an array for each user inside your array. So your data will look like this:

   Array
   (
       [jj@gmail.com] => [
           [0] => John
           [1] => Jones
           [2] => 331322
   )

To create that data structure you just need to change this:

```
$notifyemailsarray[$row['email']]=$row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']. " " . $row['userid'];
```

To this:

```
$notifyemailsarray[$row['email']] = [ $row['firstname'], $row['lastname'], $row['userid']];
```